# Struct update syntax doesn't work on borrowed data

Tags: syntax, rust

I have a struct like this with some parsed arguments:

```
struct Args {
    out: Option<String>,
    version: bool,
    help: bool,
    files: Vec<String>,
}
```

I want to recursively parse a list, returning a new modified `Args` struct every time I need to modify it:

```
fn parse(parsed: &Args, start: usize, args: Vec<String>) -> Args {
    if start >= args.len() {
        return parsed.clone();
    }

    if args[start] == "--version" {
        return parse(&Args { version: true, ..parsed.clone() }, start + 1, args);
    }
    if args[start] == "--help" {
        return parse(&Args { help: true, ..parsed.clone() }, start + 1, args);
    }
    return Args { files: args[start..args.len()].to_vec(), ..parsed.clone() };
}
```

I use the function like this:

```
fn main() {
    let args = std::env::args().collect::<Vec<String>>();
    let parsed = parse(&Args::default(), 1, args);
}
```

This code works, but I would like to type:

```
return parse(&Args { version: true, ..parsed }, start + 1, args);
```

instead of:

```
return parse(&Args { version: true, ..parsed.clone() }, start + 1, args);
```

to avoid excessive data copying during cloning. When I just remove `.clone()` it says that `Args` type expected but it got `&Args` instead.

When I dereference with `*parsed` compiler says "cannot move out of borrowed content"

Comment: Have you considered not passing the `parsed ` argument by reference?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yep, that's how I ended up. The speed gain for not cloning I got is about 7%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a type `T` is `Clone` then invoking `clone()` on a `&T` will also return a `T`, because there's no point just copying the pointer. In fact, if it *did* clone the underlying data and then returned a reference to it then you'd run into trouble because the `T` would get dropped, leaving the pointer dangling.

To turn a `&T` into a `T`, you can use the `*` operator to dereference it. However, this is going to give you problems because `parsed` is borrowed by the `parse` function, which means it has to give it back when it's finished. If you dereference it and move the values then you'll be moving out of a borrowed context.

Comment: Dereferencing doesn't work - it says "cannot move out of borrowed content".

Comment: _That's what I said it would do!_ My point may have been a little oblique, but this error should be telling you something. You either need to move the object into `parse` in the first place, rather than pass a reference, or else you are stuck with cloning.

Comment: It is interesting if we could make rust somehow accept a borrowed reference in this place - I see no reasons why not.

Comment: You want to borrow the reference and then move individual fields! Once, for example, you have moved the `files` vector onto the new `Args` instance then the original one won't have them any more. Even if your program doesn't need them, Rust won't allow you to pass around a struct with null pointers in it. You generally don't need to worry too much about the performance of cloning - the optimiser does a pretty good job to such an extent that often it's the same as not cloning. So deal with it if it becomes a problem.

Comment: So, the internals of the struct are also considered to be borrowed and can't be just used? I got it. Eh... manual memory management is something I didn't touch for fifteen years. :D Thanks!